# How can I get a Surfing Pikachu in Pokémon Yellow?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I want to know if you can still get it without using any sort of hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you will need *Pokémon Stadium* and a *[Transfer Pak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_Pak)*.

You'll need a strong team of 5 Pokémon along with Pikachu on your *Pokémon Yellow* cartridge.

Now do the following:

1. Get to round 2 (prime cup, master ball division) using any Pokémon.
2. Now enter the tournament and select Pikachu and your other 5 Pokémon from yellow.
3. For every fight, select Pikachu. You don't have to
   use him at all, just have Pikachu on your team every round.

   - **Note:** Pikachu is practically useless in the fights, so you'll need to rely on your other Pokemon to 2v3 the opponents (because you can't use a rental or registered team on Stadium).
4. After beating the Round 2 Prime Cup (Master Ball div) you'll get a small cut-scene before confirming which move to replace with Surf.

   - **Note:** You don't have to be flawless in the tournament, you're allowed to lose a battle

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Pokemon Stadium for the N64.

Sources:

http://www.ign.com/faqs/2005/pokemon-yellow-special-pikachu-edition-surfing-pikachu-faq-588815

> [...]
>
> After you beat the R-2 Prime Cup Master Ball Division with Pikachu
>   selected to go into every battle, you will see a scene of Pikachu in front of a
>   sunset that will say "You Won Using Pikachu" and then it will ask to select a
>   move to be replaced with Surf.  Congrats.

This is backed up by [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Yellow_Version)

> A Surfing Pikachu minigame, Pikachu's Beach, is included. However, to play this the player will have to first teach Pikachu Surf, which requires the use of Pokémon Stadium.

Answer (score 3):

It is still possible to obtain a Surfing Pikachu in the first generation.

You will need the following:

- A Nintendo 64
- A Transfer Pak
- Any first-generation game (Red, Blue or Yellow) with a Pikachu
- The first Pokémon Stadium game in the same language as your cartridge (note that [for Japan, it is a different game](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium_(Japanese)))

Make sure all batteries are still working.

If your game is Japanese:

- Beat the Master Ball division of the L1-30 division with a Pikachu in your party. You will then be allowed to teach that Pikachu Surf.

If your game is *not* Japanese:

- Beat the Master Ball division of the Round 2 Prime Cup using only Pokémon from your cart without saving (continuing is OK), and have your Pikachu participate in the final battle. You will then be allowed to teach that Pikachu Surf.

(Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Surfing_Pikachu#Surfing_Pikachu))